# erro when running this code, looking up did nothing

Tags: php, hash, parameters, passwords, salt

I am having great problem fixing this issue here and i am not very familiar with php. I don't see any problem missing in the code. I have searched and spent a really long time on this. However, it just keeps changing from one to another issue. the error that appears looks like this,

> Undefined variable: password in /home2/abdi/public_html/phpinfo.php/login files/login.php on line 19

here is the actual code

```
<?php  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);  session_start(); //connect to database $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","abdi_yae","abdi_yae123","abdi_ya");   if(isset($_POST['login_btn']))  {     addslashes(trim($_POST['username']));     addslashes(trim($_POST['password']));     //$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);    // $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);             $password=md5($password); //Remember we hashed password before storing last time     $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";          $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)                         {        $_SESSION['message']="You are now Logged In";        $_SESSION['username']= $username;         header("location:home.php");     }    else    {                $_SESSION['message']="Username and Password combiation incorrect";     } } ?>
```

Comment: where is the code??

Comment: My initial instinct is that "password" should probably be "$password" but without seeing any code it's hard to know.

Comment: can you edit your code section? which part is commented out and which is actual code?

Comment: Check the syntax for mysqli_real_escape_string. You need to send the connection string as a first parameter.

Comment: Please, make new lines in your code, it is highly unreadable. What I see (might be wrong), that first definition of your `$password` is commented out, while the second uses `$password`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set password variable for this.

```
$password = $_REQUEST['pass_text_name'];
```

Comment: How do you know this is the error with out looking to the code?? he may have missed a semicolon also.. :P

Comment: Undefined variable doesn't give error like undefined variable.
For semicolon error php give errors like unexpected token.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start(); //connect to database   
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","abdi_yae","abdi_yae123","abdi_ya");
if(isset($_POST['login_btn']))  {
$username = addslashes(trim($_POST['username']));  
//addslashes(trim($_POST['password']));    
//$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);    
// $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$password=md5($_POST['password']); //Remember we hashed password before storing last time 
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['message']="You are now Logged In";
        $_SESSION['username']= $username;
        header("location:home.php");
    }
    else
    {   
        $_SESSION['message']="Username and Password combiation incorrect";
    } 
} 
?>
```

Check Now Buddy. It's Done

Comment: Can you explain? $username and $password are both commented out..

Comment: This is already commented by in question and addslashes(trim($_POST['username']));  
addslashes(trim($_POST['password']));  

this both variable is here so no need to declare again.

Comment: `$password` is set but `$username` is not..even the sql query will have issues.. I was not sure how you got to an answer..the code in the question is not clear

Comment: Sorry i have edited my answear.
i forgot to declare $username in that you are right it will gave sql error.